# Is my detaching code right?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using following code to detach my DB from SQL Server express. Please advise if there is something wrong with it. I am getting an error on it.

```
"Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'EXEC master'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly."
```

The code I am using is

```
 Dim conn2 As New SqlConnection("Server=MyHomeServer\SQLExpress;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=False;User ID=sa;Password=abc123;")
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("", conn2)
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd2.CommandText = "EXEC master.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'MyHomeDBTestPWD'"
    conn2.Open()
    cmd2.Connection = conn2
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assiging this the wrong way.  You are allocating a proper SQL statement in the `CommandText` when you only need to add the Stored Procedure name.  You will then need to add a `Parameter` to your `SqlCommand`.

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("", conn2) 
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd2.CommandText = "sp_detach_db"
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbname", "MyHomeDBTestPWD")
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

If you are alternatively wanting to execute your SQL statement, then you just need to change your `CommandType` to `CommandType.Text`

Comment: Thanks a lot !  Could you also write me the code for backup and restore in the same way as you have done above?  I will be really thankful to you.

Comment: For backing up the database, you'll need to use `CommandType.Text` and specify the SQL statement yourself.  Here is the Backup page on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `ConnectionString` points already to the `Master` Database so you don't need to specify it.

   ```
   EXEC [dbo].[sp_detach_db] @dbname = N'MyHomeDBTestPWD'
   ```
2. If you want to specify the Database you should do this

   ```
   EXEC [master].[dbo].[sp_detach_db] @dbname = N'MyHomeDBTestPWD'
   ```
3. And you have the wrong `CommandType`. If you want to execute the code as it is change to `CommandType.Text`.

**CommandType.Text solution**

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("", conn2) 
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd2.CommandText = "EXEC [dbo].[sp_detach_db] @dbname = 'MyHomeDBTestPWD'"
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

**CommandType.StoredProcedure solution**

```
Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("", conn2) 
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd2.CommandText = "[dbo].[sp_detach_db]"
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbname", "MyHomeDBTestPWD")
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` namespace which contains all you need for working with the database.
There is a specific method to Attach/Detach database

```
Server mServer = new Server(".");
mServer.KillAllProcesses("attach1");
mServer.DetachDatabase("attach1", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.detachdatabase.aspx